# Validate form in rails when the user only enters spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to validate some fields so that it does not accept pure white spaces, that is, if the user only put spaces that throw an error to him.
This is inside a form of ruby ​​on rails. I already tried it with regular expressions but it did not work

Comment: `validate :field, presence: true` should do the trick

Comment: Do you want to validate on client side? On server side? On both? Show us your code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For server-side validation add following line to your model:
**validates :field, presence: true**

For client-side validation in the form for say (you have a text_field), you need to add **required: true** in the text_field tag.

This will do your work. Hope this helps